# Projecting arbitrary HTML onto a plane in 3D space

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, 3d

I need to render an essentially 2-dimensional grid in the web-browser; a chess-board, say.

But I want to give the user the option to rotate this chess-board in a 3D space, so it can be seen from arbitrary angles. (Eventually other 3D objects may co-exist in this space, but that's irrelevant for now.)

I'm now facing the choice of how to render this board. Choices include WebGL, or HTML coupled with CSS / Javascript transformations. I would prefer an HTML / CSS / Javascript solution. This would have the advantage that I can continue to use frameworks like AngularJS to manage the data on the board.

**Question:** Are currently available CSS3 + Javascript techniques reliable enough for use in production code? And can you recommend specific libraries or websites to look at?

Good browser-coverage would be nice, but is not the main concern. This will be a special purpose application; if necessary, we can ask our users to install the latest public release of Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: sure, CSS3 3D transforms are stable enough for production code, although any version of MSIE should not be considered production code... ;-)

Comment: CSS 3d transforms will work. But have you considered something like three.js?

Comment: What is a 3D "plane"?

Comment: @spassvogel: I am indeed considering three.js. But as far as I know, WebGL (and therefore three.js) is not capable of rendering HTML, which is why I'm leaning towards CSS3 transforms. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @mhelvens If the display is _just_ HTML, then yes, you should use CSS3.  WebGL / three.js won't help.  And it wasn't my comment about a "3D plane".

Comment: @Alnitak: At this point we could still go either way. But we're already using AngularJS for other parts of the app. And HTML with Angular directives would be a convenient way of specifying different layouts for the grid. --- I'll dive into CSS3 transforms. Thanks! --- Ah yes, the 3D plane comment. Sorry, misreference.

Comment: @YourAdHere: Hehe. OK, you're right. I fixed the title. ;-)

Comment: three.js offers a new CSS3D renderer. check out [http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_sandbox](http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_sandbox)